# How do i make a circle retain it shape when container resizes?

Tags: html, css

So i have the following in my html page now, which is a circle that is centered in a div:

[image]

However, what i want is for the **circle shape to retain** its form whenever a **window adjustment** is made, for example:

If i right click and **Inspect**, the **problem** is my circle becomes like so:

[image]

How do i **ensure the shape of the circle remains** even when the outer container width or height is adjusted?

**Edit: Extension from Derek.W solution**

Now what if, instead of basing it on the overall window, its based on a containing element?

[image]

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

.main_container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}

.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}

.child1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
}

.child2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "main_container">
    <div class = "outer">
      <div class = "child1"></div>
      <div class = "child2">
        <div class = "circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to preserve the aspect ratio of your circle div.  See https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp

Answer (score 0):

Checking the circle style, the width is set `10%` of the viewport width and the height is set `20%` of the viewport height so it won't be the circle.

To make the circle, it is needed to set the height and width of the same size.

`20%` of the viewport height is same as `20vh`. So you can set the width of circle as `20vh` instead of `10%` as follows.

```css
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="avc_label_style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "outer">
    <div class = "circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, but what if "outer" is a child div to another div such as "main_container"? is vh still usable in this case?

Comment: thank you, I've created an example as an extension to the above, via an update in the post.

Answer (score 0):

To make a perfect circle the height and width must be equal.

So you can get it done by

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* hight and width must be equal */
    height: 10vh;
}
```

or using `px`

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* hight and width must be equal */
    height: 120px;
}
```

I usually use the px solution passed on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only about a visual effect, you can do it using `radial-gradient`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main_container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 90%;
}

.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20%;
}

.child1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
}

.child2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50%;
  background:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,
      transparent calc(100% - 4px),#000 calc(100% - 3px) calc(100% - 1px),transparent); 
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```